# Correct Xpath for pagination grabber

Tags: xpath

Need parsing site by Content Grabber.
Can't create paggination

Code

```
<div class="pagination">
        <a href="/catalog/Kolonki_i_dinamiki_v_Donetske?page=1" title="Страница 1">  1</a>                                                         
        <a href="/catalog/Kolonki_i_dinamiki_v_Donetske?page=2" title="Страница 2">  2</a>
        <a href="/catalog/Kolonki_i_dinamiki_v_Donetske?page=3" title="Страница 3">  3</a>
```

Have tried (not working)

```
//div[@class='pagination']//following-sibling::a[1]
```

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: try with `(//div[@class='pagination']/a)[1]`

Comment: Need Content Grabber (Software for parsing) or Octoparse click next page to get content. Usual it used xPath command with expression following-sibling

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```xml
//div[@class="pagination"]/a[1]
```

It will find the next `a` bellow the div.

The `following-sibling` you used, selects all siblings **after** the current node.

Comment: when this expression, grabber click by loop only one page, but does not pass to the page 2,3,4....etc

Comment: you need to iterate programmatically increasing the last value `a[1]` passing the sequence until the end. You can get the last page using `//div[@class="pagination"]/a[last()]`.

Comment: `//div[@class="pagination"]/a[last()]` this expression always click every last page in pagination list. i need expression with `following-sibling` ONLY. It should click each by each page. Start 1 page, click 2 page, click 3 page....etc

Comment: Working example for [this site is](http://www.anekantprakashan.com/sugar-mill-machinery-suppliers/india):
`//tr[@class='pagination']//span/../following-sibling::td[1]/a`

Working example for [this ste is](https://www.hg.org/lawyers/california):
`//a[@class='currentpage']/../following-sibling::li[1]/a`